# Audio Fade in and Fade Out with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to fade in and fade out but I don't know what's wrong in my code. Fade in works but fade out does not.

Below the code:

```
        var mPlayer = document.getElementById("pad-c");
        $(mPlayer).prop("volume", 0.0);

        var isPlaying = false;

        function playAudio() { 
            mPlayer.play(); 
            isPlaying = true;
        } 

        function pauseAudio() { 
            mPlayer.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
        } 
        function playPauseC() {
          if (isPlaying == true) {
            $(mPlayer).animate({volume: 0.1}, 5000);
            pauseAudio();
          } else {
            $(mPlayer).animate({volume: 1.0}, 5000);
            playAudio();
          }
        }
```

Comment: please note that Stack overflow works in English as a common language

Comment: Living and learning! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are *pausing* the audio at the same time as the fadeout. Use the `complete` parameter on [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to pause the audio **after** the fadeout is complete.

```
function playPauseC(){
  if(isPlaying == true) {
    $(mPlayer).animate({volume: 0.1}, 5000, function() {
      pauseAudio();
    });
  } else {
    $(mPlayer).animate({volume: 1.0}, 5000);
    playAudio();
  }
}
```